# Smooth hover transition?

Tags: css, hover, transition

I seem to be having trouble with the animation aspect of a hover description. The hover itself works fine and appears exactly where it is placed; however, there seems to be no fade effect when hovering over or away from the element. Instead, the description box appears sharply within the 0.5s listed in the CSS, and disappears the same way. I'm looking to create a smooth, transitioning effect, where the description box fades in and out. Can someone please help me adjust this?

CODE:

```
#description {
    opacity:0;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:30;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:249px; 
    margin-top:-5px; 
    border:1px solid #000; 
    width:230px; 
    height:299px;
    color:{color:text};
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out; }

#description a {
    color:{color:text};
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out; }

#sidebar:hover #description {
    opacity:0.6;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out; }
```

Comment: Only apply the transition once, in the normal state. It's redundant in the hover state. Also, could you provide a fiddle so we can see exactly what you see please?

Comment: I provided a fiddle on the comment bellow. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
#description {
    opacity:0;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:30;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:249px; 
    margin-top:-5px; 
    border:1px solid #000; 
    width:230px; 
    height:299px;
    color:{color:text};
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#description a { color:{color:text}; }
#description:hover { opacity:0.6; }
```

Comment: Go fish, unfortunately. The hover transition still behaves the same.

Comment: hmmm. wish I could see your full code.  Here, try removing the selectors from #description.  So it would just be #description:hover { opacity:0.6; }  I edited it above. ^

Comment: Here's a fiddle that shows a part of the code I'm working on so far. Two IMG's will be placed in the empty middle boxes, and a hover overlay to appear over the right box. When you hover over it, you can see the choppy in-and-out movement. http://jsfiddle.net/Ke8uP/

Answer (score 0):

Tried it itself in my code.
Just get rid off opacity and it will work.
See youtiming dot com for demo.

'opacity' is a css property that you need to specify the level value: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a live example on fiddle I just made

This is the HTML Markup

```
<div class="kid">
<img src="https://cleansites.us/images/katie-kid.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="750" />
<img src="https://cleansites.us/images/katie-adult.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="750" />
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
.kid {
    max-width:250px;
    position:relative;
}

.kid img {
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
    height: auto;
    transition:.6s ease;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:12;
}
.kid img:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
.kid img + img {
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cdsaekv9/7/